# Length of tangent line segment to 2 circles

Tags: geometry, circles

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4lJHUDH1P5UEZ4QzNYcTNYQWs/edit?usp=sharing

The image of the problem can be accessed in the above website.

Two semicircles are tangent to each other. The semicircle with center D has a radius of 4, and the semicircle with center C has a radius of 2. Segment AC is tangent to the larger semicircle and intersects the smaller semicircle at B. What is the length of segment AB?

[image]

Comment: post the image here, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\triangle ACD$ is a right triangle with $CD=6$, we have
$$AB=AC-BC=\sqrt{6^2-4^2}-2=2\sqrt 5-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Tangent-Secant theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_Secant_Theorem) to get $(AB+2)^2=2\dot(2+8)$. Solving this yields $AB=\sqrt{10}-2$.